# trigger with a select condition

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-insert

I want to create a trigger that doesn't perform a insert if the insert 
for column 2 already exists in the table and the value for column 1 in the table is different to value inserted for column 1. 
I've done

```
create trigger tr1
 on dbo.table
 after insert, update
 as
 begin 
  declare @col1 varchar(20)
  declare @col2 varchar(20)

 if ( 
  exists(
   select column2 from table
   where column2='@col2'
        ) 
  and @col1 <> select column1 from table
  where column2='@col2'
    )
 begin
  RAISERROR('Error', 16, 1);
  ROLLBACK
 end
end
```

Comment: Look at `INSTEAD OF` insert triggers. Here is a nice example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372794/simple-t-sql-instead-of-trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure i've understood what you are tryng to do but an easy way to check for existing values with TRIGGERS is to use the transaction tables.

- inserted for UPDATE and INSERT
- deleted for DELETE

1.

```
create table some_table(col1 int , col2 int)
go
```

2.

```
create trigger tr1 on dbo.some_table after insert, update
as
begin 
    declare @cnt int 

    select 
        @cnt = count(*) 
    from some_table as t
    inner join inserted as i on t.col1 = i.col1 and t.col2 = i.col2

    if isnull(@cnt,0) > 1
    begin
      RAISERROR('Error', 16, 1);

      ROLLBACK
    end
end
```

3.

```
insert into some_table(col1, col2) values(1,2)
go
insert into some_table(col1, col2) values(2,3)
go
--HERE the trigger will crash
insert into some_table(col1, col2) values(1,2)
go
```

I personally prefer the UNIQUE INDEX approach :)

Comment: thank you very much for being so didactic explaining :D